# If the recipient has their preview pane on/open, if that is counted as an open? specifically for Outlook

Tags: marketing-cloud

I ran a report in which I found the number opens are 5 times grater than the audience.
specifically for Outlook

If the recipient has their preview pane on/open, if that is counted as an open?  specifically for Outlook.

Also are hardly a chance of forwarding an email.

Comment: Can you please limit your question to a single topic, so asking only about open behaviour. It is not clear what you mean by asking: "Also are hardly a chance of forwarding an email."

Comment: There are hardly a chance of forwarding an email. - here I mean that sometimes if we forward an email so will that be also counted as open and here there is approx no chance of forwarding an email. For more clarity I mentioned that.

Next time surely I will give specific deatils :-)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, any case of an email loading - be it preview or opening it in a new window, will result in an open being tracked (as the tracking pixel is loaded on each view).

If you are working with data views, you can use the _Open.IsUnique field, to limit the number of opens to only show a single open per combination of subscriber and email. You can read more about Open and other data views [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.mc_as_data_view_open.htm&type=5).